# How to migrate community builder data from joomla 1.5 to joomla latest version?

Tags: migration

I have purchased joomla sp upgrade plugin but i am not get any options to trasfer community builder data from joomla 1.5 to joomla latest version, can any one please provide us solution thanks.

Comment: community builder data is community builder data so you should look for the community builder migration/upgrade procedure.

Comment: Have you read the documentation at https://www.kainotomo.com/products/sp-upgrade/documentation/extensions ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using SP Upgrade It states on the extensions page that it supports community builder.
[SP Upgrade](https://www.kainotomo.com/products/sp-upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

i just do it manual, just install the latest version of community builder and then migrate the db from old to latest version. When you do like this you will control what is the difference between them. I think you also can do this via [redcomponent.com](http://redcomponent.com)